# how to pass IF condition in sum case when

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**#my code**

```
select('a.client_location_id as location_id','b.name as location_name','c.name as client_name',
                
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 1 employee_qty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_in'),
                
DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 2 employee_qty  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_out')
            )
```

i want to do IF conditioning like , **if type = 1** result is SUM employee_qty AS **e_qty_in** and **if type 2** the result is SUM employee_qty AS **e_qty_out**,

[image]

**#table**

Comment: you should use `employee qty` in THEN,  for example SUM(CASE WHEN a.type = 1 THEN employee_qty ELSE 0 END) as e_qty_in

Comment: You use MySQL Tag in your question. But with MySQL this request seems to work `SELECT 
sum(if(type=1,employee_qty,0)) as 'e_qty_in', 
sum(if(type=2,employee_qty,0)) as 'e_qty_out' 
FROM yourTable `

Comment: You can try something like this: `DB::raw("SUM(IF(type = 1, employee_qty, 0)) as e_qty_in")`

Comment: stackover flow...? ..???? No more news... ? No answers...? No following...?